# Knocking out parameter in TF tensors

Tags: tensorflow

I have a neural network which is currently written just as tensors as I don't understand layers well enough yet.

I would like to impose a condition on the network i.e. write one of the (many) parameters in terms of all the others - how does one do this?

Comment: Can you give a little pseudo code to explain what you want to achieve, it's a bit unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure pseudo code would help, perhaps it's better to explain more generally without referencing TF specifically. I have a NN which contains N free parameters that I am fitting. I have a constraint on the system that allows me to write one of those free parameters in terms of all the others, reducing the number of free parameters by one. This is what I would like to implement. Thanks.

Comment: Edit outside the 5 minutes: I guess what I want to do is at each point in the optimization process have one of the biases be a function of all the other parameters in model, and so vary with them according to that function.

Comment: In a typical network you have thousands, even millions of weights and biases. I'm not sure I see the point of the exercise, but I'll provide an answer as best I understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to implement a constraint on your bias units. In fact it doesn't matter much what constraint you want to place on them. The way to implement such a feature would be to run your optimizer, which updates all trainable variables (your weights and biases in the network). Now your biases will be in violation of the constraints you want to apply. After the optimizer run you want to normalize the biases to achieve your desired constraints. To do that you'll need to use `tf.control_dependencies` to ensure your constraints depend on the optimizer running. It should look something roughly like this:

```
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(...).minimize(cost)
with tf.control_dependencies(train_op)
  # some code that computes a normalized bias based on your constraints
  new_train_op = tf.assign(bias, normalized_bias)
```

When you run the code you can ask for `new_train_op` instead of `train_op` and it will compute everything through the normal optimizer, and eventually the update op which alters the bias to impose the desired constraint.

If you don't want to allow the optimizer to performs its update and normalize after the fact you would have to implement the optimizer itself. That's actually not so hard to do, you can do it entirely with tensorflow constructs your used to and python, but worthy of another question.